# S.O.S Beginner in Data Science and Needs Guidance

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, matlab, artificial-intelligence

I hope I'm in the right place to post

my first query here, and to to be brief, I'm an electrical engineering student, working on a task of "Monitoring electrical machines through Partial Discharge data using an AI technique" but I'm struggling in all directions,

what AI technique to use - I'm planning to use ANNs but still need your advice -, which one works best with my problem (continuous electrical signal - voltag, pressure, tempreture ...- as inputs, and decision making - state of the system, mean time to failure, as output (classification, forcasting)

What to use, Matlab (which i'm familiar with), or Python. GPU and Cloud computing

Now, what's more important for me, where to get some practical example for solving problems like mine in (matlab or/and Python)

I admit that my question may not be well formatted, but still hope to get some guidance

thanks for all

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1483/6633) for guidance on how to write a good question. As of now, your question is far too broad and vague, and I am voting to close it unless you edit it appropriately.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Cross Validated. Have you taken the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)? I hope this doesn't sound unwelcoming, but I think that in order to learn the most from this experience, you should first follow a course in Statistics or at least a MOOC in Data Science, and then come back here to ask some questions. If you don't want to do that, then I suggest you describe in detail your problem and providing sample data. Then we could be able to help you.

Comment: Please also amend your title to reflect the nature of the question, not your desire for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Dilip.  You will need to present your project and questions clearly before other readers will respond.  As for the responses you'll receive here, they will provide guidance only and will not do the work for you.

As for a coding language, I highly recommend using Matlab in this case.  It's a high-level language and as such you can work more directly with machine learning concepts and methods, which I think is the point of the project.  There will definitely be a learning curve involved, but I think Matlab will be far more welcoming and less tedious than the other options you've mentioned.